# Незван(н)ые гости

Tags: орфография

Озадачился, когда Ворд подчеркнул мне слово "незванные (гости)", написанное через два Н. Неужели тут одно Н? По-моему, даже звучит два...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фактически написание *незваный гость* является традицией. Ничто не мешает нам поставить двойное Н и считать слово причастием в этом устойчивом сочетании, есть при нем зависимые слова или они **подразумеваются**.

> Саша Черный. Солдатские сказки/ Безгласное королевство (1932)
> **Благословил он незванных гостей** начерно: квас-то был ядреный, в подполье мореный, на семи травах настоенный…
>
> Ф. Ф. Эрисман. Общественная гигиена (1871-1908)
> Возможность умереть от холеры или тифа или от какой другой эпидемической болезни, правда, пугает нас, но страх этот ведет лишь к тому, что в минуту опасности мы хватаемся за первое встречное средство, не сознавая необходимости долголетнего, усиленного и научного труда для удаления от нас холеры и **других незванных гостей.**
>
> Ф. К. Сологуб. Мелкий бес (1902)
> Теперь она удивилась неожиданному посещению, но **приняла незванных гостей** любезно.
>
> Е.А. Салиас. Аракчеевский подкидыш (1889)
> Солдат явился **звать незванных гостей** в кухню пить чай.
>
> Н. С. Лесков. Чающие движения воды (1867)
> У Венерки не было ни рассудительности Кинжалки, ни его сил, но зато у нее была в теле ртуть, не дававшая ей ни одной минуты покоя и заставлявшая ее беспрестанно скакать через гряды и пугать звонким лаем **всех незванных гостей**, приплывавших из города портить бакшу Пизонского.

Автор текста именно так произносит и даже специально акцентирует : *незваННый гость* (= непозванный, неприглашенный). Он не обязан ставить здесь каких-то обязательных поясняющих зависимых слов, его полное право. Квалификация признака в качестве постоянного/непостоянного мне кажется достаточно надуманной. Не признак, а нормальное определение субъекта - *незванный*. Можно заменить слово **гость** любым другим : незванный ураган, незванная грусть, незванный форсмажор... Очевидно, в традиции написания одного Н в *незваном сабже* сыграло свою роль прилагательное *званый* в словосочетании **званый вечер**. Но мы не должны слепо следовать чьим-то предпочтениям, у нас есть свои личные авторские соображения. Да-да, у каждого есть свое мнение в разумных пределах.

> Н. С. Лесков. На ножах (1870)
> И когда Горданов в большом затруднении расхаживал по своей комнате, его еще более изумило то странное обстоятельство, что пред самыми сумерками **господин Ворошилов, незванный, непрошенный**, явился его навестить.
> А.К. Шеллер-Михайлов. Дворец и монастырь (1900)
> Не нужно мне пестунов! **Выгнать незванного советника**! Еще и на митрополию не возведен, а неволею обязует!

Как отмечала [@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F) в ответе на другой вопрос, мы здесь сталкиваемся с академическим стремлением все поставить в узкие разрешительные рамки. Да пусть уж автор сам рассудит : прилагательное у него или причастие.
Почему мы так боимся вариативности? Чтобы ловить на ложной якобы безграмотности и снижать баллы за неакадемическую орфографию(((
(Все примеры -  русский Нацкорпус)

Comment: Возможно, надо различать: А)причастие "незванный" - тот, которого просто не звали, не ожидали; Б)прилагательное "незваный" - тот,которого не хотят видеть, нежелательный, неприятный. Не исключено, что второе значение со временем стало вытеснять первое.

Answer (score 3):

Звучание - не основание для правописания. "Незваные" образовано от глагола несовершенного вида "звать", причем нет ни приставки ("не" не считается), ни зависимого слова, поэтому пишется "незваные"

Answer (score 1):

Отглагольные прилагательные званый, незваный пишутся одной буквой Н, так как обозначают постоянный признак.

Прилагательное званый образовано от бесприставочного глагола  несовершенного вида, при этом оно входит в пару "званый - званный", то есть при наличии зависимого слова мы имеем причастие званный: гости, званные к обеду.

Приставка НЕ не изменяет написания слова: это всё тот же постоянный признак:незваный, нежелательный гость.

Стоит также отметить, что выбор Н/НН не делается по произношению, которое зависит от положения относительно ударного слога. А причина одна: наше письмо является смысловым, а не фонетическим. По написанию слова (по его морфемному составу) мы можем  передать о нем дополнительную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это причастие, написание НН у которого зависит от 4-х условий:
 - глаг., от которого оно образовано, д.б. сов. вида;
 - д.б. приставка (кроме НЕ);
 - д.б. суф. -ова-/-ева-;
 - д.б. зависимые слова

Answer (score 0):

Ответ однозначный: незваНый.

Это материал средней школы.

Comment: В средней школе и материал дается усредненный, специально подобранный и отсортированный... *Незваный гость* - часть известной поговорки, не стоит на ее основе уничтожать причастие *незванный*.
> М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)  
― Подсолнечное масло здесь вот при чём, ― вдруг заговорил Бездомный, очевидно, **решив объявить незванному собеседнику войну**, ― вам не приходилось, гражданин, бывать когда-нибудь в лечебнице для душевнобольных?

Comment: В средней школе изучаются простые формальные правила, имеющие ограниченный круг применения. О происхождении этих правил, об их значении  никто даже не задумывается - считают, что они даны нам сверху в утвержденном виде. Но здесь не средняя школа, поэтому обсуждается более широкий круг вопросов. В то же время на школьных экзаменах лучше ограничиться вариантом "незваный".

Comment: Доходит до смешного)  
 Ушаков :  
>САМОЗВАННЫЙ, самозванная, самозванное (книжн.). Присвоивший самовольно, незаконно чужое имя, звание. Самозванный ревизор.  
(пометок, прич. или прил. - нет)

Ожегов/Шведова :  
>САМОЗВАНЫЙ 
ая, -ое. 1. Являющийся самозванцем. 2. Взявший на себя какие-н. обязанности без назначения, самовольно. Самозваный советчик.  
(пометок - нет)

Ефремова :  
>САМОЗВАННЫЙ 
**прил**. 1) Присвоивший себе незаконно чужое имя, звание. 2) разг. Взявшийся за какое-л. дело по своей инициативе, по собственному почину, без назначения.

В школе - как писать???

Comment: В школе однозначно: самозваный. С одной "Н".

Comment: Здесь не средняя школа, разумеется.
Но на ЕГЭ по русскому языку придется писать однозначно: незваный.